# ChatCompletion Vs Completion API: reasons or use cases to favor the latter?

Tags: python, openai-api

I have just finished an online class that teaches how to use the OpenAI APIs ChatCompletion and Completion on Python.

The class explains that:

- openai.Completion => for single-turn tasks.
- openai.ChatCompletion => for multi-turn conversations with a model to build on previous prompts. Chat models often perform just as well as Completions models on single-turn tasks. ~10x cheaper than openai.Completion

My question is: if openai.ChatCompletion can do everything that openai.Completion does **and** is much cheaper, are there any situations or use cases where it might make sense to favor openai.Completion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Openai /v1/completions vs. /v1/chat/completions end points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76192496/openai-v1-completions-vs-v1-chat-completions-end-points)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your questions is yes, The completion models are typically not as restricted. You can more readily get the completion model text-davinc--003 to return data on topics which are sensored than it is to get the more powerfule GPT-4 model todo so via the chat interface.